# iOS: Set tabs title min font size of the PageMenu

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, font-size

I'm using the [PageMenu](https://github.com/PageMenu/PageMenu) component in my `objective-c` application in order to display tabs. All is working perfectly but I want to set the minimum font size of the `tabs` title. Is there a way to add this condition on the parameters of the `PageMenu`?

Those are the parameters that I use:

```
NSDictionary *parameters = @{CAPSPageMenuOptionMenuItemSeparatorWidth: @(1.0),
                             CAPSPageMenuOptionUseMenuLikeSegmentedControl: @(NO),
                             CAPSPageMenuOptionMenuItemSeparatorPercentageHeight: @(0.1),
                             CAPSPageMenuOptionScrollMenuBackgroundColor: [UIColor whiteColor],
                             CAPSPageMenuOptionSelectedMenuItemLabelColor: [Utils colorWithHexString:@"e60028"],
                             CAPSPageMenuOptionUnselectedMenuItemLabelColor: [Utils colorWithHexString:@"666666"],
                             CAPSPageMenuOptionMenuItemWidth: @(itemsWidth),
                             CAPSPageMenuOptionAddBottomMenuHairline: @(YES),
                             CAPSPageMenuOptionBottomMenuHairlineColor: [UIColor lightGrayColor],
                             CAPSPageMenuOptionSelectionIndicatorColor: [Utils colorWithHexString:@"e60028"],
                             CAPSPageMenuOptionMenuItemFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:13.0],
                             CAPSPageMenuOptionCenterMenuItems: @(NO)
                             };
```

Comment: you can set this in CAPSPageMenuOptionMenuItemFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:13.0] here

Comment: @SaurabhJain how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can't find the default property provided by [PageMenu](https://github.com/PageMenu/PageMenu), because they didn't added minimum font size behaviour for tab. In case you are much interested in changing or setting minimum font size of tab, you can customize the **MenuItemView.swift** class.

[image]

Comment: The problem is that I don't have a label. I use the default title of the UIViewController

Comment: Yeah, I do understand that. When you pass a title of UIViewController, the PageMenu tries to set the same title as tab title. So tab title which actually displaying from **MenuItemView** class, that's why you have to do some code changes in the ** MenuItemView** class in oder to set the minimum font size